# Ubuntu: How do I set my app to start with the system?

Tags: ubuntu, login, script, boot, ubuntu-10.04

I want 3 application to start as I login. How do I do it?
(I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 if it makes any difference)

Comment: just to be clear, you want this stuff started up when you login to X? or when the system boots?

Comment: preferable when I login to X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up System -> Sessions. (Or just search the menus for "sessions".) There you can add any application for autostarting purpose. (I am just not sure about where its located on the 10.04 release so check the whole System menu for "Session").

Comment: System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications.
I thought this would be available just by command line... XD

Comment: Well... you will have to use command line also by the time, don't worry. At least autostart is avaliable through a gui more or less in 2010. ^^" :)

Comment: i think that's running *gnome-session-properties* ... obviously you could *start* it by the terminal but it's a Gnome config dialog, so it needs an X to display on.  i'm sure it's just tweaking variables in some config file somewhere but i'm not sure where.